# Regex matches URL path fraction for MVC previous URL constraint

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm looking for a URL path fraction regex pattern. It should match:

```
prefix/controller/action/
controller/action/
/controller/action/
/controller/action?param=val
/controller/action?param=val&param2=val
...
```

I would like to use it in a route constraint for the previous URL in MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following pattern, which should at least be a good start if not exactly what you need:

```
(?:prefix/|/)?controller/[a-z]+(?:/|(?:\?[a-z]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:&[a-z]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*))
```

Key points:

- `(?:prefix/|/)?` – optionally (per the terminal `?`) starting with `prefix/` *or* (per `|`) just `/`, which we choose not to capture (per `?:`)
- `controller/`
- `[a-z]+` – the action
- `(?:/|(?:\?[a-z]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:&[a-z]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*))` – ending with `/` *or* (per `|`) `?` followed by at least one parameter and value

It matches all your sample inputs:

```
prefix/controller/action/
controller/action/
/controller/action/
/controller/action?param=val
/controller/action?param=val&param2=val
```

You can test it in a [related RegexPlanet demo](http://fiddle.re/1keud6).